# Symfony2: entity asserts that accept an array of types?

Tags: validation, symfony, annotations

I have an entity with the field $companies.
This field has to store an array of Company objects. So I described assert this way:

```
@Assert\Type("Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Company")
```

But it's always invalid because from my form i receive array of Companies but this assert wants it be not array but just one Company.

So how to overcome this? I suppose that it has to be something like that:

```
@Assert\Array(Type("Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Company"))
```

Answer (score 13):

Since the question is tagged for **Symfony2.x**, for the sake of completeness I have to point out that the new validation constraint [All](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/All.html) introduced since *version 2.1* can do the whole job.

For each array or traversable objects (e.g. a Doctrine `ArrayCollection`), you can do the following:

```
/**
 * @Assert\All({
 *     @Assert\Type(type="Acme\MyBundle\Entity\EntityType")
 * })
 */    
protected $arrayOfEntities;
```

So, the **Symfony2.1 users** that are reading your question should prefer this elegant and clean solution.

Answer (score 8):

There is no built-in constraint that would meet your requirements, therefore you'll have to define your own.

Constraint definition:

```
namespace MyProject\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
* @Annotation
*/
class CollectionOf extends Constraint {
    public $message = 'This value should be a collection of type {{ type }}';
    public $type;

    public function getDefaultOption() {
        return 'type';
    }

    public function getRequiredOptions() {
        return array('type');
    }
}
```

Validator definition:

```
namespace MyProject\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;

class CollectionOfValidator extends ConstraintValidator {
    public function isValid($value, Constraint $constraint) {
        if ($value === null) {
            return true;
        }
        
        if (!is_array($value) && !$value instanceof \Traversable) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($value, 'collection');
        }
        
        if (count($value) === 0) {
            return true;
        }
        
        $type = $constraint->type == 'boolean' ? 'bool' : $constraint->type;
        $function = 'is_' . $type;
        
        $primitiveTest = function_exists($function);
        
        foreach ($value as $item) {
            if (
                ($primitiveTest && !call_user_func($function, $item)) ||
                (!$primitiveTest && !$item instanceof $type)
            ) {
                $this->setMessage($constraint->message, array(
                    '{{ value }}' => is_object($item) ? get_class($item) : gettype($item),
                    '{{ type }}'  => $constraint->type
                ));
                
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        return true;
    }
}
```

The above validator works for both, collections and arrays.

---

#### Edit (2011-06-29)

Import your own constraints:

```
// My\TestBundle\Entity\Company

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use MyProject\Validator\Constraints as MyAssert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Company {
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(...)
     * @Assert\NotNull
     * @MyAssert\CollectionOf("My\TestBundle\Entity\Employee")
     */
    private $employees;
}
```

To use annotations constraints you'll have to enable them in confirguartion file:

```
framework:
    ...
    validation:
        enable-annotations: true
```

Comment: The annotation "@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\CollectionOf" in property My\TestBundle\Entity\Company::$company does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.

Comment: Sorry, but it falls now with new error:
My\TestBundle\Validator\Constraints\CollectionOf contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint::getTargets

Comment: added
`public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::PROPERTY_CONSTRAINT;
    }
`
and now it's not falling with errors but always says me "This collection should be of type My\TestBundle\Entity\Company"
It's strange because i'm sure that i check right values in form: it 100% is instance of Company

Comment: @VitalyP: It seems that you're not using the newest version of Symfony. [`Constraint::getTargets()` method](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraint.php#L202) is no longer defined as abstract. But that's not a problem, just copy that definition into your own constraint class.

Comment: @VitalyP: Well... I guess I made a mistake somewhere in the validator, I've never tested this code. But I'll test it tonight (I'll need a similar validator anyway) so try to fix it yourself and post fixed version or be patient. ;)

Comment: @Crozin: Thank you. I'll try to fix and post it here.

Comment: It should, but it not:
Fatal error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string in /var/www/solid/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 2070

Comment: The only error I found was the @Annotation missing tag for the Constraint. This code works for me!